# Android: Задать цветной радиус границ TextView, если ещё неизвестен цвет

Tags: android, textview, background, border

Есть обыкновенный `TextView`. Как задать ему определённый радиус границ **не** через XML?

[image: Round TextView]

Если, конечно, есть способ, удовлетворяющий условию ниже, буду благодарен.

Я объясню, почему так принципиально. Цвет заднего фона данного `TextView` хранится в файле, а конкретнее, `Properties`. Выбирается он пользователем произвольно (например, #000000 - это чёрный, #FFFFFF - это белый, и так далее до бесконечности). А вот как другим людям предложили сделать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781902/rounded-corner-for-textview-in-android), [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203501/android-creating-a-circular-textview) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316354/how-to-make-text-view-shape-circle-and-set-different-background-color-based-on-c) уже должен быть известен нужный цвет и задан в теге `solid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по выдаче гугла на запрос

> [android rounded corners programmatically](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20rounded%20corners%20programmatically)

Вас устроит ответ по этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19152013/3212712)

```
 PaintDrawable shape =  new PaintDrawable();
 //устанавливаем радиус скругления углов в пикселях
 shape.setCornerRadius( 8 );
 //устанавливаем любой цвет, например красный
 shape.setColor(Color.RED);

 //устанавливаем полученный фон к-л вьюхе
 View view = ...;
 view.setBackground(shape);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Постараюсь вскоре проверить. Сейчас времени пока нет.

Comment: почему-то пишет ошибку, что метод `setColor` не существует.

Comment: @L'Esperanza, попробуйте тогда GradientDrawable вместо PaintDrawable